# Why doesn't this setInterval code work?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the background color of the body every second but it does not work. What did I do wrong?

```
var colors = [
    "red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "red"
    ],
    rand = Math.ceil(Math.random() * colors.length - 1),
    t = setInterval(function() {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[rand];
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Why are you doing all 3 of those in one chunk? Separate them into 3 statements (with semi-colon) and go through each one. That'll help you deduce which one is broken, and help with debuging.

Comment: @meder It only changes the background color in one second on page load but doesn't proceed to change the color on the following second.

Comment: @Ryan even when I separate it, I still can't find an error...

Comment: You are setting `rand` only once.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are defining the value `rand` once and then reusing it every time. You mean:

```
var colors = [
"red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "red"
];
t = setInterval(function() {
    // use floor instead of ceil and then you can skip the -1
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[rand];
}, 1000);
```

<s>Also, you're using commas to separate the commands, while this won't always break (I can think of at least one situation where it won't), it is generally a bad idea because it implies that there is some larger structure going on.</s>

As per `patrick dw`'s comment, you are right to use commas. It caused me to have a mental slip-up in that context, especially when `rand` was moved into the `setInterval`'s function. I would suggest that you might want to re-write that as `var colors, t; colors =` to help people understand more (at one point it looked like I was not the only one who made that mistake)

Comment: OP is only using commas to declare multiple variables. By using a semi-colon instead of a comma, you've created a global variable (if they're not already global).

Answer (score 2):

`rand` is only being set the once, try this:

```
var colors = [
    "red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "red"
    ],
    t = setInterval(function() {
        var rand = Math.ceil(Math.random() * colors.length - 1);
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[rand];
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "red"];
t = setInterval(function() {
  var rand = Math.ceil(Math.random()) % colors.length;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[rand];
}, 1000);
```